# Logging into website using Mechanize to fill in form?

Tags: ruby, forms, mechanize

I am trying to log into a site using Mechanize.

The form I am trying to fill out is the only one for on the page and is called "admin-login". The user name field has a name of "un" and the password field has a name of "pw".

My error output is:

```
myserver:in `addProduct': undefined local variable or method `form_name' for main:Object (NameError) from login.rb:82:in `<main>'
```

My code is:

```
def addProduct

  agent = Mechanize.new

  page = agent.get( 'correctURL' )
  correctURL_form = page.form( 'admin-login' )
  form_name.un = 'username'
  form_pass.pw = 'password'

  page = agent.submit( form_name, form_pass, correctURL_form.buttons.first )
  puts page.body

end
```

Am I missing something here? I was told that this was fairly easy to pick up but I am really struggling with the basics of Mechanize.

Comment: Where do `form_name` and `form_pass` come from? You try to use them as if they are instances of an object with "setters", but don't show where they are instantiated. And, Ruby is complaining about the same thing.

Comment: I made them up as variables. Should I be using something from the form? I thought the .un and .pw at the end of each got the form field I was assigning text to.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use something more like:

```
admin_login = page.form( 'admin-login' )
form_name = 'username'
form_pass = 'password'

page = agent.submit( form_name, form_pass, admin_login.buttons.first )
```

You can't name a variable with a '.' in it:

```
form_name.un = 'username'
form_pass.pw = 'password'
```

Ruby will assume that you're talking about instances of some class, called `form_name` or `form_pass`, which have methods called `un` and `pw` respectively. And, since those aren't defined, Ruby complains.

Instead, use a simple variable name and Ruby will be happy.

Also, note that variable names like `correctURL_form` are not Ruby-like. We use snake_case names for instance variables.

Comment: Thank you. I just made up correctURL_form for the question. I tried getting rid of the .un and .pw and am getting this error, /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-2.7.1/lib/mechanize.rb:535:in `submit': undefined method `add_button_to_query' for "username":String (NoMethodError)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I have gotten it to work. Here is my corrected code.

```
def addProduct

agent = Mechanize.new

page = agent.get( 'correctURL' )
correctURL_form = page.form( 'admin-login' )
correctURL_form.un = 'username'
correctURL_form.pw = 'password'

page = agent.submit( correctURL_form, correctURL_form.buttons.first )
puts page.body

end
```

This got the output of the success page. Thanks all for the help!